# How to provide region of interest (ROI) for edge detection and corner detection in Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab

I have a movie file, in which I am interested in recording the movement of a point; center of a circular feature to be specific. I am trying to perform this using edge detection and corner detection techniques in Matlab.

To perform this, how do I specify a region of interest in the video? Is subplot a good idea?

Comment: Maybe better on dsp.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1):

If you already extracted the frames, you can use **imroi** and **roifilt2**.

Check out the following section from help:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f19-12807.html